# Data Recovery from RAID5 disk - Promise Pegasus with Apple OSLion and Thunderbolt connection

Tags: macos, data-recovery, raid-5

I have a Promise Pegasus R6 - 12 TB RAID 5 disk for major storage purposes. One of the six 2TB hard disks were dead and the company provided me with a replacement.  When the disk was inserted it installed itself as a separate partition and their service advised me to delete it and reinstall it.  However, during this process the partition with 10 TB was deleted. It was silly of me to try this out.

Now the Promise says that I need to contact professional data recovery services.  I live in France nearby Geneva and the search nearby identified no available services.

Could anyone suggest any method - software or service for a similar data recovery problem please ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may only need to rebuild your partition table if you didn't actually remove any data. I would boot a rescue cd and give [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) a try to see if it detects the 'lost' partition(s) during a 'Quick Analyze'.

Unfortunately, testdisk is less than awesome at repairing HFS+ partitions so you'll have to take the partition information it gives you and feed it to pdisk.

Overview of steps:

```
./testdisk /dev/sda1 
Analyze / Quick Analyze
Note starting block and number of blocks in partition
Boot Lion Recovery Mode
Drop to terminal
pdisk /dev/disk0
c
enter start block
enter number of blocks
enter name
w
q
```

Above referenced from [Repair HFS+ Partition table](http://perrohunter.com/repair-a-mac-os-x-hfs-partition-table/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this type of "recommendation" thread is discouraged here, but one company I know of that provides that type of service is called OnTrack - you can probably work from there to find similar companies in your aread.